# create two executable jar for the same project?

Tags: java, jar

I have developed an Java application with RMI,JPA and H2DB, look at the screenshot is my project :

[image]

All I need is to have two JARs (client and server) with imports to the libraries described in the screenshot.
the problem is that netbeans does not generate two JARs for the same project :

[image]

this box allows you to create a single jar for the project...
is there a solution for this problem?

thans in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your project structure, I would suggest using an ant script to build your jars. That way you can specify which source files and jar dependencies to include in your client and server jars.

Answer (score 1):

Break up your project into three modules. One for shared code, one for server and one for client. Having it all together like you have will eventually result in unmaintainable code (and sooner rather than later..).

Comment: Depends on what build tool you use. With e.g. Maven you have an aggregator that ties is all together and build it all in one go as required but they are still separate modules. And Netbeans understand all the dependencies of the module out of the box and know how to deal with it.